# Jquery href with hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using tis code for tab navigation.

```
function hashIt(toHash) {
    toHash == "" 
     ? window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace( /#.*/, "") 
     : window.location.hash = toHash;
    return false;
}
```

and also i am using jquery popup on page onload. a hyperlink in the popup is not working,
if i remove the hashIt function its fine.
but i want both. Please help me out.

Ramesh.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Your function doesn't make sense.  You could just do `window.location.hash = toHash;`.  If toHash is blank, you replace the entire hash with a blank string.  If it's not blank, you set the hash to toHash.  Beyond that, you should show more of your code, including the popup code and the code that calls hashIt.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should just be

```
function hashIt(toHash) {
    window.location.hash = toHash;
}
```

without all the extra logic.  Then to clear the hash, just call `hashIt("");`

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `return false;`, then check if it still works... (suspecting something)